# AngularUI Datepicker without filter, what's happening?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, datepicker

I was using a angularUI datepicker in my webapp when I suddently came across this:

http://plnkr.co/edit/MLnWCtYHMNqLeuFOetWH?p=preview

In particular I am setting the date in my controller like this:

```
$scope.getDate = function() {
   $scope.dt = new Date(2015,0,1);
};
$scope.getDate();
```

then in my html I display the date in this two ways:

```
<pre>With angular date filter date is: <em>{{dt | date:'medium' }}</em></pre>
<pre>Without angular date filter is: <em>{{dt}}</em></pre>
```

As you can see in this plunker, I have selected the date "01/01/2015" (january 1st, 2015) and if I see the plunker with the Angular date filter I get the correct date and time.

However, if I remove the filter, I get the same date 1 hour in the past.

It is surely a problem of timezones, but I cannot find any sources of this behavior, so I wanted to understand what's going on. Is there any explanation or a website to browse?

Also, what will arrive at the server? Do I have to do some special formatting on the server? (i cannot test this atm)

Don't know if this matters (I think yes), but my browser lives in Italy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both displayed dates are the exact same moment. They are just formatted differently. When you instantiate a date, your browser uses your current timezone (1st of January 2015 at midnight in Italy, so UTC+1).

When using a date filter, Angular displays your date in your current timezone whereas it displays the UTC date without.

Just try:

```
var date = new Date(2015,0,1);
date.toString(); // -> "Thu Jan 01 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)"
date.toISOString(); // -> "2014-12-31T23:00:00.000Z" (Z means UTC time)
```

As a rule of thumb, always use ISO8601 date format when sending your dates to the server (it is what JSON.stringify does when serializing an object with date values).